# Using mouse hook, I wanted to get windows explorer path where mouse is clicked or pointed in Java

Tags: java, windows, mouselistener

Is it in any possible to get the absolute path of the folder which is open in windows explorer when navigated or clicked using mouse. I am only able to get mouse co-ordinates.

What I want to achieve is, to be able to copy a file to a path where mouse clicks and 'ctrl + v' is pressed, I wanted to run Robocopy script instead of windows copy. For this I need to get the destination registered using Java Mouse hook.

Let know know if there are even better ways to do it using java.

Any help would highly be appreciated !!!

Comment: No way to achieve that in Java, at least without going to native code/API.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am search for a native way to do this. Any recommendation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Windows API, but if you find something useful, you can see if JNA will help you.

Comment: No luck, I somehow am not getting a way to achieve it..